# "Что ж, я дурак, что ли?" Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

В газетной статье встретила предложение "Что ж, я дурак, что ли?"
Наверно, я бы поставила знаки препинания иначе: "Что ж я, дурак, что ли?" А вы? Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Наверно, я бы поставила знаки препинания иначе: "Что ж я, дурак, что ли?" А вы?**

Это разговорное выражение, в котором интонационные паузы могут размещаться по-разному. Чаще всего именно так, как Вы понимаете; тогда запятая должна быть после местоимения, а местоимение интонационно сливается со **что** или **что ж**. Например:

> Да что же я, дурак, что ли? (Н.Гоголь, "Мёртвые души")

Но после местоимения паузы может не быть. Тогда знаки препинания могут отсутствовать:

> Что ж я столбом, что ли, перед ней стоять буду? (Салтыков-Щедрин)
>
> Что же мне целоваться с мошенниками и подлецами, что ли? (А.П. Чехов)

Либо автор может разорвать интонационное слияние "что" с последующим местоимением:

> Что ж, я не понимаю, что ли? (М.Булгаков)

Подробно и интересно о предложениях с "что — что ли", "что ж — что ли" написано в книге Н.Ю. Шведовой "Очерки по синтаксису русской разговорной речи".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, в газете написано корректно: **"Что ж, я дурак, что ли?"** Попытаюсь объяснить свою точку зрения.

Начну с того, что фраза "Что я, дурак, что ли?" (без *ж*) встречается повсеместно (в частности, в Нацкорпусе) и запятая везде стоит после *я*. 
Интонационно и по смыслу эта фраза распадается на два вопроса: "Что я? Дурак, что ли?" Почему именно "Что я?", а не "Кто я?" Во-первых, так принято говорить. Во-вторых, вопрос не о реальной характеристике вашей личности (Кто я?), а скорее о  поведении в конкретной ситуации. (*― Какой марки машина? ― Не скажу ― что я, дурак? [Олег Алямов. Неспящие (1997) // «Столица», 1997.04.01)]*)
Можно также считать, что это сокращенный вопрос: "Что я из себя представляю?"

Добавление частицы *ж* меняет дело. Эта частица подчёркивает, усиливает что-то, но что именно? Вопрос "Что я?"? Вряд ли, тут нечего подчеркивать. Теперь она вместе с *что* обращена ко всей фразе в целом: "Что ж? Я дурак, что ли?" Изменился смысл, изменилась и интонация.

Подчеркну еще раз, все сказанное — не более чем мое личное видение ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ исправлен.

Правильно: **Что ж я,  // дурак, что ли**?

Деление фразы делается по-разному, например:

(1) **И что же я, // не понимаю, что ли**, что зима ― это одно, а млыво ― совсем другое? [Михаил Шишкин. Венерин волос (2004) // «Знамя», 2005]

(2) ― **Что же, я не понимаю, что ли?** Слон — другое дело. Слоны — животные полезные. [М. А. Булгаков. Собачье сердце (1925)]

Первый вариант кажется более правильным с точки зрения интонации. Первая часть (***и что же я***) имеет вопросительную интонацию (повышение тона), вторая часть (***не понимаю, что ли***)  также является вопросительной. Вопрос как бы повторяется дважды.

Comment: Jasmin, у Вас как-то отрывками изложено. При чем обособление приложения? У Шишкова приложение (герой называет себя дураком), а у нас нет. "Различаем сочетания что ж или что + же". И в чем же различие?

Comment: Ответ исправлен.