# Сколько здесь нужно запятых?

Tags: пунктуация

Что она, дурочка что ли, отвечать на комментарий?

Я бы поставила знаки так, но хотелось бы услышать еще мнения с обоснованием. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что мы знаем о частице "что ли"?

> § 1693. К вопросительным частицам относятся частицы *а, ли (ль), не ...
> ли, неужели, никак* (прост.), *ужели* (устар.), *разве, что за, что, **что
> ли,** как*. Все эти частицы совмещают значение вопросительности с более
> или менее ярко выраженной модальной окрашенностью.
>
> Частицы *что, что ли, а, ка*к относятся к разговорной, непринужденной
> речи. Частица *что* или открывает собою вопросительное предложение, или
> следует за вынесенным в начало предложения именем: *Что, он опять
> опаздывает?; Он что, опять опаздывает?* Частица *что* выражает также
> переспрос (*— Ты меня слышишь? — Что?*). Частица *что ли*, вносящая
> оттенок фамильярности, обычно заключает собою предложение (*Заснул что
> ли?; Опять скандал, что ли?*), но может и открывать его. Эта частица
> очень часто употребляется вместе с частицей *что*; они обрамляют
> предложение (*Что, заснул, что ли?; Что, опять скандал, что ли?*).
> Частица *а* заключает собою вопрос; она вносит значение побуждения к
> ответу (*Пойдем, а?*) или выражает переспрос (*— Пойди сюда. — А?*).
> Частица *как* имеет собственно вопросительное значение: *Как (ну как),
> согласен?*; при переспросе: *— Я не пойду. — Как? Как не пойдешь? (Как
> это?; Как это (не пойду)?*).
> Вопросительные частицы часто выступают в свободном соединении друг с другом: *Что, устал, а?; Что, не подождать ли нам?; Заснул, что ли,
> а?; Ну как, согласен, а?*; Соединения *что если, а если, а вдруг*
> оформляют вопрос-опасение: *Что если (а что если) он не придет?; А
> вдруг опоздаем?*
>
> § 1695. Модальные частицы вносят в предложение разные значения
> субъективного отношения к сообщаемому: *Что ли мне чайку попить* (разг. речь) (колебание).

http://www.rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html#1695

Обратимся к нашему предложению: *Что она, дурочка что ли, отвечать на комментарий?* К чему относится частица *что ли* и какая она — вопросительная или модальная?

Если считать модальной частицей со значением колебания, то запятые стоят верно: то ли дурочка, то ли нет. Но ведь у нас нет этого значения. Здесь не колебание "дурочка — не дурочка", здесь явно вопрос: *Разве она дурочка?* И ещё поясняется, почему её могут посчитать дурочкой, — потому что она отвечает на комментарий. Если нет запятой,  *дурочка что ли*  — оборот, его можно убрать и конструкция останется корректной. Убираем: *Что она отвечать на комментарий?* — бессмыслица, конструкция некорректна.

Если здесь вопрос, то вопросительная частица отделяется: *Что она, дурочка, что ли, отвечать на комментарий?*  Убираем *что ли*: *Что она, дурочка отвечать на комментарий?* Всё нормально.

Ещё одно — структура.  Эта частица очень часто употребляется вместе с частицей *что*; они обрамляют предложение (*Что, заснул, что ли?; Что, опять скандал, что ли?*). У нас тоже есть такое обрамление **что она — что ли**. Это тоже говорит за запятую.

Можно и так:  *Что, она дурочка, что ли, отвечать на комментарий?* Но это уже зависит от автора, куда он поставит.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила,, все четко и ясно.

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны, можно подумать, что запятая перед ***что ли*** не нужна, опираясь на [правило](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122):

> Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: *Среди товарищей есть эдакие поэты, **лирики что ли**, проповедники любви к людям* (М. Г.) — ср. не в составе оборота: *Лошадей, **что ли**, у вас нет?* (Остр.).

Но, на мой взгляд, предпочтительнее выглядит вариант с обособлением:

*Что она, дурочка, что ли, отвечать на комментарий?*

[**ЧТО ЛИ**, *частица*. Обособляется](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_761).

Может, еще будет полезно почитать ответы на вопрос ["Что ж, я дурак, что ли?"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438352/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B6-%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (Хотя здесь обсуждается другая запятая, но запятая перед "что ли" стоит везде.)

Answer (score 1):

> Я бы поставила знаки так

Согласен с Вами. Тем более что можно оправдать такую пунктуацию правилами (см. ответ Александра). Даже если постановку ещё одной запятой перед "что ли" можно оправдать примерами из литературы, перед Вами такая задача не стоит. Что касается другого обсуждения, на которое Александр ссылается в своём ответе, то там действует такое правило (см. словарь О.А. Остроумовой, О.Д. Фрамполь):

> В конце предложения **что ли** всегда обособляется: *Ворюга, что ли? — спрашиваю* (С. Довлатов); *Сапоги там какие-то, что ли?* (А. Куприн); *Очумел, что ли!* (К. Паустовский).